# O que é a camada de aplicação/aplicativo em uma arquitetura de camadas? Qual a diferença para a camada de domínio (regras de negócio)?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, arquitetura-de-software

Em uma arquitetura de camadas ou em camadas, o que é a camada de aplicação ou camada de aplicativo?

Qual a diferença em relação à camada de domínio e regras de negócio?

Comment: Entendi nada, você postou e você mesmo fechou como duplicata? O_o

Comment: @Articuno Isso mesmo, só para ficar mais fácil de achar a pergunta em buscas.